# Why is the ListView not updating when returning from Service?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-activity, android-service

Choose_Country

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

public class Choose_Country extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_choose__country);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

}
```

Choose_CountryFragment

```
package com.A.B;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;

import com.A.B.service.GetNumberService;

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class Choose_CountryFragment extends Fragment {

    private RadioGroup radioGroup;

    public Choose_CountryFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_choose__country, container, false);

        radioGroup = (RadioGroup) rootView.findViewById(R.id.country_choice_radio);
        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
        {
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                switch(checkedId){
                    case R.id.A:
                        // do operations specific to this selection
                        break;

                    case R.id.B:
                        // do operations specific to this selection
                        Intent explicitGetNumberServiceIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), GetNumberService.class);
                        explicitGetNumberServiceIntent.putExtra("country", "B");
                        getActivity().startService(explicitGetNumberServiceIntent);
                        break;
                    case R.id.C:
                        Intent explicitGetNumberServiceIntentN = new Intent(getActivity(), GetNumberService.class);
                        explicitGetNumberServiceIntentC.putExtra("country", "C");
                        getActivity().startService(explicitGetNumberServiceIntentC);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }


}
```

GetNumberService

```
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * An {@link IntentService} subclass for handling asynchronous task requests in
 * a service on a separate handler thread.
 * helper methods.
 *
 *
 */
public class GetNumberService extends IntentService {
    private ArrayList<String> mobileNumberList = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static final String ABC = "com.A.B.ABC";
    private final String LOG_TAG = GetNumberService.class.getSimpleName();

    public GetNumberService() {
        super("GetNumberService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;


        String NumbersJSON = null;


        if (intent != null) {
            String chosenCountry = intent.getStringExtra("country");

            try{

                final String BASE_URL = "http://1.1.1.1:8080/WebServices/country/";

                Uri buildUri = Uri.parse(BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                        .appendPath(chosenCountry).build();

                URL url = new URL(buildUri.toString());
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Read the input stream into a String
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                if (inputStream == null) {
                    // Nothing to do.
                    return;
                }
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                    // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                    // buffer for debugging.
                    buffer.append(line + "\n");
                }

                if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                    // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                    return;
                }

                NumbersJSON = buffer.toString();

                JSONArray Numbers_Array = new JSONArray(NumbersJSON);

                for(int i = 0; Numbers_Array.length() != 0 && i < Numbers_Array.length(); i++) {
                    NumberList.add(Numbers_Array.getString(i));
                }

                Intent NumbersIntent = new Intent(ABC);
                NumbersIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("Numbers", NumberList);

                LocalBroadcastManager localBroadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
                localBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(NumbersIntent);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error ", e);
                // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attempting
                // to parse it.
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (final IOException e) {
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return;
    }


}
```

ChooseNumber

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import com.a2ndnumber.a2ndnumber.service.GetNumberService;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Choose_number extends AppCompatActivity {

    static ArrayList<String> mNumbersList;

    private final BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if(intent.getAction().equals(GetNumberService.ABC)){
                mNumbersList = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("NumberList");
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_choose_number);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(GetNumberService.ABC);
        LocalBroadcastManager bm = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
        bm.registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, filter);
    }

}
```

ChooseNumberFragment

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class Choose_numberFragment extends Fragment {


    private ArrayAdapter<String> NumberListAdapter;

    public Choose_numberFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        NumberListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item_numbers, R.id.list_item_textview, Choose_number.NumbersList);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_number, container, false);

        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_List);
        listView.setAdapter(mNumberListAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

In ChooseCountry Fragment , I choose a country. What should happen is, it should go to service, get data and populate array list and send the populated array list to ChooseNumberFragment/ChooseNumber Activity.

What is actually happening is, I am able to debug till GetNumberService's onHandleIntent method's return statement and I notice the array List is populated with values from REST services. But the app doesn't populate the arrayLIst in CHooseNumberList acitivity or fragment.

I am not getting any exception as well.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: How you add those fragments? I am not seeing any getSupportFragmentManager in your activity code. Are you adding those fragment using xml?

Comment: @AmadYus That is where I am struck at. I am new to Android programming and I am struck here.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Choose_number Activity does receive the List through the BroadcastReceiver, however all it does is assign it to its own instance variable `mNumbersList`. You would need to notify the Fragment that the List has changed so that it can notify the ListView that the data has changed. The ListView has to know that it's data has changed so it can update and redraw itself. Call [`notifyDataSetChanged()`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html&ved=0ahUKEwizobutwPjOAhWCwiYKHY2dBgcQFggbMAA&usg=AFQjCNEcL0CWsKaj7myt-gwKrKA8syZwhw&sig2=Yua706UbLSfB1jGUddjpeQ) from the Fragment to acheive this.

Your question is also a little unclear. It asks about not being able to inflate a Fragment but then in the details is asking about the ListView not changing. If, in addition to the ListView problem, you don't know how to inflate a Fragment, you need to call getSupportFragmentManager() and then create a FragmentTransaction. You can read the [Fragments Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) to learn how to do this.

Comment: May I know how to do that. I am a newbie to Android programming.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the method you call to make this happen.